# What are the ideal conditions of this flower

Tags: flowers

How can I take care of this flower and what season does it bloom? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *Hippeastrum*, commonly but incorrectly called an *Amaryllis*.

They are often sold planted in a pot *after* they have been kick-started into growth, and they then don't need any special care except watering them. Like most bulbs, once they have started growing they will flower the first year however badly you mistreat them - everything the plant needs to flower is already stored in the bulb.

In the northern hemisphere they are often sold as "Christmas presents," and are grown in artificial light and temperature conditions before being sold to make them flower at Christmas or early in the new year. Their natural flowering time is early spring.

In warm climates they can also be grown outdoors.

If you want them to grow and flower in successive years, you need to give them the correct treatment to make them go dormant, and then keep them in a cool environment before the next growing season. See https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=118 for the details.